# Command to pad zeros to specific locations in binary numbers?

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

I need to pad zeros to specific locations in binary numbers. Looping the array form of a binary number such as `dec2bin(43)` and adding the zeros and adjusting the size sounds reinvention of the wheel.

How to pad zeros efficiently to binary numbers in Matlab?

**Looping**

```
positions=[1,3,6];
x=de2bi(43);
xx=flip(x);    

kk=1;
for ii=1:length(x)+length(positions)
    if isequal(positions(kk),xx(ii))
         %Transfer the tail from ii by one index ahead,
         %left out here because I think my method is bad!
         x(ii)=0;
         positions=positions+1;  %Increase positions by one now due to one padding
         kk=kk+1;
    end
end
```

which feels too much reinvention: basically how to get 0 just before Y like from xxxxYabcd to xxxx0Yabcd where xxxxYabcd is a binary number?

**Example**

> **Input**
>
> > 101011, (1,3,6)
>
> **Output**
>
> > 100100110
> >
> > 1x010x11x  (showing location of zeros clearer with x where zeros inserted)

Comment: If you are looking for efficiency you will probably need a solution that can pad all your numbers at once (rather than one by one). Running each of the presented solution 10000 times will take a few seconds, whilst running my solution on a 10000x5 matrix only takes a fraction of a second.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Please provide some context for your question.

Comment: @starblue easier to think this as bit shifting problem? The Q can be reformulated as a bit shifting prob from many locations onwards, I feel there may be an elegant bit shift solution to do this. I don't know yet whether there exist some specific academic term for this problem. I outlined the bit shifting idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840409/bitshift-from-a-specific-bit-onwards-in-binary-number), I am not yet sure how to do it elegantly. The padding zeros problem has too much attention in manipulating arrays, hopefully getting now more attention in terms of bits.

Answer (score 1):

Although not much of a conceptual improvement, the following will do automatic re-indexing and assignment of the old values on a pre-padded matrix:

```
>> xx
xx =
     1     0     1     0     1     1

nPads = length(positions);
nPadsShifts = 1:nPads;           
y = ones(1, length(xx) + nPads); % re-indexing on the new array
y(positions + nPadsShifts) = 0;  % padding values
y(y==1) = xx;                    % set original bit values


>> y
y =
     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using just indexing. The positions of the zeros to be inserted in the extended vector are `insertzeros+(1:length(insertzeros))` (where `insertzeros` is `[1 3 6]` in your example):

```
input = [1 0 1 0 1 1]; %// example data
insertzeros = [1 3 6]; %// example data

output = ones(1,length(input)+length(insertzeros));
output(insertzeros+(1:length(insertzeros))) = 0;
output(output==1) = input;
```

Comment: So far the fastest method, +1 for being the fastest -- I don't know yet why this is fastest. Tested with warmed-up code with the small example of the question.

Comment: @hhh Compared to thewaywewalk it uses matrices rather than cell arrays. And compared to my solution it uses logical indexing rather than subscripted indexing. The steps taken by this answer and the one by gevang are pretty much the same so thats why calculation times are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Race begins! Mendo wins, gevang is a good second, thewaywewalk is the third and jaheruddin comes in fourth. The Shai's [bitshifting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20840926/164148) is implemented in the shai function, unfortunately not yet getting it run faster.

**Results**

```
gevang :2.2e-05
thewaywewalk :5.6975e-05
mendo :2.2102e-05
jaheruddin :0.0001693
shai (poor hhh-implementation) 5.3288e-04
```

**Warmed-up testing of the answers**

```
function test_padding_zeros()

    function myOutput=gevang(xx,positions)
        nPads = length(positions);
        nPadsShifts = 1:nPads;
        myOutput = ones(1, length(xx) + nPads); % re-indexing on the new array
        myOutput(positions + nPadsShifts) = 0;  % padding values
        myOutput(myOutput==1) = xx;                    % set original bit values
    end

    function myOutput=thewaywewalk(x,positions)
        idx = numel(x):-1:1;
        myOutput = num2cell(x);
        myOutput(2,idx(positions)) = {0};
        myOutput = [myOutput{:}];
    end

    function myOutput=jaheruddin(myInput,positions) % myInput can be a row vector or a matrix!
        n = size(myInput,2)+numel(positions);
        myOutput = false(size(myInput,1),n);
        myOutput(:,setxor((1:length(positions)),1:n))=myInput;
    end

    function myOutput=mendo(myInput,positions)
        myOutput = ones(1,length(myInput)+length(positions));
        myOutput(positions+(1:length(positions))) = 0;
        myOutput(myOutput==1) = myInput;
    end

    function out = bizarreBitShift( bNum, fromBit, shiftAmount )
        % construct a mask
        msk = uint32( (2^( fromBit - 1 ) )-1 ); 
        shiftPart = bitand( uint32(bNum), bitcmp(msk) ); % bitcmp - complement of bits
        staticPart = bitand( uint32(bNum), msk );
        out = bitshift( shiftPart , shiftAmount );
        out = bitor( out, staticPart );
    end

    function myOutput=shai(myInput,positions)
        shiftAmount=1;
        myOutput=sprintf('%d',myInput);
        myOutput=bin2dec(myOutput);
        k=0;
        for ii=1:length(positions)
            fromBit=positions(ii)+k;
            myOutput=bizarreBitShift(myOutput, fromBit, shiftAmount);
            k=k+1;
        end

        myOutput=ismember(dec2bin(myOutput),'1');
    end




positions = [1 3 6]; %// example data
myInput = [1 0 1 0 1 1]; %// example data

ggevang=@() gevang(myInput,positions);
tthewaywewalk=@() thewaywewalk(myInput,positions);
mmendo=@() mendo(myInput,positions);
jjaheruddin=@() jaheruddin(myInput,positions);
sshai=@() shai(myInput,positions);

timeit(ggevang)
timeit(tthewaywewalk)
timeit(mmendo)
timeit(jjaheruddin)
timeit(sshai)

end
```

Comment: interesting, I used a `tic`/`toc` based benchmark code and the answer of gevang was as double as fast as Luis Mendo's. But for 10000 runs of every function.

Comment: This is how my answer can be timed as well, note that it is slower, but can also accept matrices. My point was that if you want speed, consider whether you can do this with a 10000x5 matrix rather than with 10000 1x5 vectors. --- Some comments on the code: I removed the global declarations as anonymous functions automatically have access to the parent workspace, and I also renamed `input` as that is actually a function name. For easy comparison I have renamed all in and outputs to `myInput` and `myOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for efficiency it can never hurt to try various options. Here is another way to do it:

```
M = magic(5)>3; % Example matrix
positions = [2 3 6]; % Desired padding columns in resulting matrix

n = size(M,2)+numel(positions);
R = false(size(M,1),n);

R(:,setxor(positions,1:n))=M
```

Comment: while benchmarking it appeared that your solution does not give the correct result for the OP's input. Have you considered that the OP counts the position starting with the last bit?

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately I cannot understand how this works so cannot get a time for you, did some warmed-up testing of different answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20799855/164148). If you clarify your answer, I will add your method also to the race, merry Christmas! :)

Answer (score 0):

Shai provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20840926/164148) bitshifting solution for a single binary number. I use it below to pad the zeros, the solution can probably made far faster -- currently being one of the slowest solution (some unnecessary dec2bin) or about the same speed as Jaheruddin's solution.

```
function out = bizarreBitShift( bNum, fromBit, shiftAmount )
    % construct a mask
    msk = uint32( (2^( fromBit - 1 ) )-1 ); 
    shiftPart = bitand( uint32(bNum), bitcmp(msk) ); % bitcmp - complement of bits
    staticPart = bitand( uint32(bNum), msk );
    out = bitshift( shiftPart , shiftAmount );
    out = bitor( out, staticPart );
end

function myOutput=shai(myInput,positions)
    shiftAmount=1;
    myOutput=sprintf('%d',myInput);
    myOutput=bin2dec(myOutput);
    k=0;
    for ii=1:length(positions)
        fromBit=positions(ii)+k;
        myOutput=bizarreBitShift(myOutput, fromBit, shiftAmount);
        k=k+1;
    end

    myOutput=ismember(dec2bin(myOutput),'1');
end

positions = [1 3 6]; %// example data
myInput = [1 0 1 0 1 1]; %// example data

sshai=@() shai(myInput,positions);
timeit(sshai)
```

**Timing**

```
ans =

   5.3288e-04
```