# Bitshift from a specific bit onwards in binary number?

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

My idea for bit shifting binary numbers from many locations onwards is outlined below. I formulated this problem first as a zero-padding problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791048/command-to-pad-zeros-to-specific-locations-in-binary-numbers) but I am now starting to feel there may be an elegant bitshift solution. I can do bitshift such as `bitshift(5,1)` where `101` to `1010` but how to do it from a specific bit? For example, `101` from a certain bit shifted such as from the second bit onwards so that `101` to `1001`?

**One shifting from a specific location onwards**

```
myBinary=de2bi(23);      %bits in increasing order, bi2de format from DEC number
                         %23=11101(BI decreasing), BI_bi2de=10111(increasing)

shiftAmount=3;           %amount to shift the bits
threshold=3;             %bits shifted in the increasing order from threshold

%Correct result:
%10111 --> 10'111 ---> 10000111 (shifted 3 times from the threshold 3)

tail=myBinary(1:threshold);
myBinary(1:threshold)=[];
myBinary=[zeros(1,shiftAmount),myBinary];
myBinary=[tail, myBinary] %in increasing order
myBinary=flip(myBinary)   %in decreasing order
```

**Shifting many times from many locations onwards**

> From 10010 to 11 and then back to 10010, the last step requires 3 bit shifts. So the zeros could be stored as `[0,2,3]` in order to get from 11 to 10010 back. My idea is to use the above *'One shifting'* method many times but feeling there may be easier solution here.
>
> ```
> 11--- bit 0 onwards ---> 110 
>   --- bit 1 onwards ---> 1010 
>   --- bit 3 onwards ---> 10010
> ```

---

> **How to bitshift from a specific location in a binary number onwards?**

Comment: What is wrong with the answers to your previous question, it should not be hard to adjust them for a variable shift? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791048/command-to-pad-zeros-to-specific-locations-in-binary-numbers

Comment: I might undo my downvote if you can show how you have tried to build on the answers of the previous questions before asking here.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin The thing is that I expect the bitshifting solutions to outperform the zero-padding solutions if implemented well enough. So I see far better to concentrate only on bit shifting rather than padding zeroes. Of course, the comparison could be interesting but so far enough work with bit shifting...

Answer (score 1):

use a mask to seperate the input into the "shifting part" and "static part".
Shift the "shifting part" and then re-assemble the number using a `bitor` operation:

```
function out = bizarreBitShift( bNum, fromBit, shiftAmount )
% construct a mask
msk = uint32( (2^( fromBit - 1 ) )-1 ); 
shiftPart = bitand( uint32(bNum), bitcmp(msk) ); % bitcmp - complement of bits
staticPart = bitand( uint32(bNum), msk );
out = bitshift( shiftPart , shiftAmount );
out = bitor( out, staticPart );
```

Comment: Taking some time to understand this, `bizarreBitShift(12,2,10)
Undefined function 'bitnot' for input arguments of type 'uint32'.`, getting probably soon working...testing..

Comment: Thank you +1, implemented your bitshifting idea in the other thread to pad binary numbers with zeros [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20799855/164148), not yet got it run fast  but trying...

Answer (score 0):

What about these two lines:

```
a = [ 1 0 1 0 1]
pos = 3;   %counting started with 0 from the right
n = 1;     %number of shifts

b = de2bi( 2^(pos+n)*bi2de( a(1:end-pos) ,'left-msb' ) ,'left-msb' );
b(end-pos+1:end) = a(end-pos+1:end);
```

returns:

```
b =

     1     0     0     1     0     1
```

and for `pos = 1` as well as `pos = 2`:

```
b =

     1     0     1     0     0     1
```

**If you would count your bits the same way Matlab does, from left to right, with the most siginificant bit on the right, the code is much easier:**

```
b = de2bi( 2^(pos+n)*bi2de( a(pos+1:end) ) );
b(1:pos) = a(1:pos);
```

---

**And regarding your *"Shifting many times from many locations onwards"* request I really don't see why this should be different from your previous question.**

Comment: @hhh: have a look at my last edit; I simplified a little and implemented a n-times shift.